# How did Captain America survive being frozen for 70 years in ice?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-avengers, captain-america-the-first-avenger, marvel-cinematic-universe

As [asked on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-did-Captain-America-survive-being-frozen-for-70-years-in-ice):

> With a metabolism 4X the average human's, the notion that his body wouldn't have wasted away doesn't make sense. Did the comics provide any explanation for how he was able to survive?

Comment: Just because his normal metabolishm is higher than a normal human's doesn't mean that it couldn't be much, much, much less when hibernating. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation#Human_hibernation )

Comment: When frozen, metabolism is going to be zero, so 4 X zero is still zero.  Surviving being frozen, if implausible, would not be implausible because he has a higher than normal metabolism.  That's really your problem with that concept?

Comment: Because comics.

Answer (score 11):

The only reason given in the movie is just that he was exposed to super soldier serum which made him able to survive and even in some animated TV shows, there is no other explanation given rather than this.

The same question is present on Scifi [How did Captain America survive freezing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14248/how-did-captain-america-survive-freezing) with the same answer. There are some un-sourced claims present on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Captain-America-The-First-Avenger-2011-movie/How-did-Captain-America-survive-being-frozen-for-70-years-in-ice) too.